# What is the right time to eat fruits?

Tags: nutrition, fruits, time-of-day, meal, guidelines

There's no doubt that eating fruit is important to our overall health and well-being. But is there exist general guidelines/directions which should be followed while consuming fruits?

For example: A fruit should only be consumed only during breakfast/morning and should be avoided during night?

Of course, the answer may vary depending on the exact fruit under discussion, but what is general advice for layman's knowledge for consuming fruits?

Comment: The right time to eat fruits is when you're hungry.  The wrong time to eat fruits is when you're not hungry.

Answer (score 2):

**In the Morning on an Empty Stomach/Between Meals** - Fruits are recommended to be eaten on an empty stomach or in between meals because at this time digestion happens fairly quick and also different types of enzymes are used by the body to digest the fruit. Fruits contain simple sugars, which need time to be completely absorbed by the body. When fruits are eaten in between meals or on empty stomach, all the nutrients, the fiber and simple sugars are processed well in the body.

**Pre/Post Workout** -
The sugars of fruits will be used by the body for getting immediate energy before workout and helps in refilling the emptied energy stores in the body after workout.

Source : http://www.md-health.com/Best-Time-to-Eat-Fruits.html

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Health SE. Could you please provide some references to support your claims (in accordance with the Health SE policies: http://health.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Thank you. BW

Comment: source of the answer is added at the bottom.

Comment: While this may be true for many people, it is not always the case - for example, in Diabetes (or early insulin resistance "prediabetes"), glycemic index is very important to consider.  Eating fruit with other foods can help slow absorption of its sugars and reduce blood sugar spikes.